# Detect duplicate pages in a large pdf

Tags: pdf

I am searching for a solution.  Is there a way to detect duplicate pages in a large pdf file?  These are NOT copied files - one can easily do that in python code.  I am talking about pages that our sophisticated visional system would quickly detect as "the same" document, but were likely created at different times and with different systems and software.  In other words, pages that may be structurally very different.

Comment: As you're ruling out similarities in pdf object structure as a criterion, I'd propose asking your question in a more general context, not limited to pdfs but instead for graphics in general.